# Mo's algorithm to compute "power" of array

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Recently, I learned [Mo's algorithm](http://blog.anudeep2011.com/mos-algorithm/) for the square-root decomposition of queries in order to speed up solutions to certain problems.

In order to practice implementation, I have been trying to solve [D. Powerful array](http://codeforces.com/contest/86/problem/D) (a past contest problem on Codeforces) using this idea. The problem is as follows:

You have an array with [image: n] integers [image: array].

Consider an arbitrary subarray [image: subarray]. Define [image: Ks] to be the number of occurrences of an integer [image: s] in this subarray. The *power* of a subarray is defined as the sum of [image: Ks*Ks*s] for all integers [image: s] (note that there are only a positive number of terms for which this is not zero).

Answer [image: q] queries. In each query, given two integers [image: l] and [image: r], compute the *power* of [image: subarray].

It holds:

[image: limits1]
[image: limits2]
[image: limits3]

Using Mo's algorithm, I have written code that solves this problem offline in [image: complexity]. I am certain that this problem can be solved using this algorithm and time complexity, as I have inspected the accepted code of others and they also use a similar algorithm.

My code, however, [gets a time limit exceeded verdict](http://codeforces.com/contest/86/submission/17158297).

Below is the code I have written:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

int sqt;
long long int ans = 0;
long long int arr[200005] = {};
long long int cnt[1000005] = {};
long long int tans[200005] = {};

struct el
{
    int l, r, in;
};

bool cmp(const el &x, const el &y)
{
    if (x.l/sqt != y.l/sqt)
        return x.l/sqt < y.l/sqt;
    return x.r < y.r;
}

el qr[200005];

int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
    int n, q, a, b;
    std::cin >> n >> q;
    sqt = sqrt((double)(n))+27;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> a >> b;
        a--; b--;
        qr[i].l = a;
        qr[i].r = b;
        qr[i].in = i;
    }
    std::sort(qr, qr+q, cmp);

    int li = 0; //left iterator
    int ri = 0; //right iterator
    ans = arr[0];
    cnt[arr[0]]++;

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        while (li < qr[i].l)
        {
            ans -= cnt[arr[li]]*cnt[arr[li]]*arr[li];
            cnt[arr[li]]--;
            ans += cnt[arr[li]]*cnt[arr[li]]*arr[li];
            li++;
        }
        while (li > qr[i].l)
        {
            li--;
            ans -= cnt[arr[li]]*cnt[arr[li]]*arr[li];
            cnt[arr[li]]++;
            ans += cnt[arr[li]]*cnt[arr[li]]*arr[li];
        }
        while (ri < qr[i].r)
        {
            ri++;
            ans -= cnt[arr[ri]]*cnt[arr[ri]]*arr[ri];
            cnt[arr[ri]]++;
            ans += cnt[arr[ri]]*cnt[arr[ri]]*arr[ri];
        }
        while (ri > qr[i].r)
        {
            ans -= cnt[arr[ri]]*cnt[arr[ri]]*arr[ri];
            cnt[arr[ri]]--;
            ans += cnt[arr[ri]]*cnt[arr[ri]]*arr[ri];
            ri--;
        }
        tans[qr[i].in] = ans;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
        std::cout << tans[i] << '\n';
}
```

Can you suggest any non-asymptotic (or possibly even an asymptotic) improvement that can speed up the program enough to pass the time limit?

I have already tried the following things, to no avail:

1. Using a vector instead of an array.
2. Using two nested pairs instead of struct.
3. Using only one pair, and then using a map to try to recover the correct order of answers.
4. Adding some various constants to `sqt` (such as [image: 27] in the code above).
5. Overloading the < comparison operator within the struct `el` itself.

I feel like I'm missing something important, since the other codes I have inspected seem to pass the time limit with quite a bit of leeway (around half a second). Yet, they seem to be using the same algorithm as my code.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You define the power of a subarray in terms of a, l, r, and s, but then each query has only a, l and r specified. Is the sum taken over all s?

Comment: Yes, it is the sum over all s. I have added this to the question, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: The description link you provided http://blog.anudeep2011.com/mos-algorithm/ says at the bottom, "Note: That code will give TLE on submission, it will give AC if fast I/O is added. Removed fast I/O to keep code clean."  Seems like IO might be the problem, since cin/cout aren't very fast.  I suggest checking the IO time vs. the compute time and see if IO could be the cause of the time-limit-exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could strength-reduce

```
    while (li < qr[i].l)
    {
        ans -= cnt[arr[li]]*cnt[arr[li]]*arr[li];
        cnt[arr[li]]--;
        ans += cnt[arr[li]]*cnt[arr[li]]*arr[li];
        li++;
    }
```

to

```
    while (li < qr[i].l)
    {
        ans -= (2*cnt[arr[li]]-1)*arr[li];
        cnt[arr[li]]--;
        li++;
    }
```

and likewise for the others.

Comment: It seems that changing this allows my code to become accepted, although only barely (4960 ms).

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the **MO's sorting function comparator function cmp**.

**Your version:**

```
bool cmp(const el &x, const el &y)
{
    if (x.l/sqt != y.l/sqt)
        return x.l/sqt < y.l/sqt;
    return x.r < y.r;
}
```

**Optimisation:**

If the **block is even**, you can **sort the R in descending order**, and if the **block is odd**, you can **sort the R in ascending order**. This will minimise the movement of R pointer considerably when moving from one block to another.

**My code:**

```
bool cmp(const el &x, const el &y)
{
    if (x.l/sqt != y.l/sqt)
        return x.l/sqt < y.l/sqt;
    return (x.l/sqt & 1) ?  x.r < y.r : x.r > y.r; // avoids TLE
}
```